# Can VBA UDF entered on worksheet combine cell references and local variables (jagged array)?

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, function, user-defined-functions

I have created a public function whereby I create a jagged array.

```
Public Type CpnData
    'coupon info
    cpn_no_prime As Integer
    fc_cpn_nbr As Integer
    'departure info
    dep_airpt As String
    dep_date As Date
    dep_time As String
    'arrival info
    arr_airpt As String
    arr_date As Date
    'carrier info
    mkt_flt_carr As String
    mkt_flt_nbr As Integer
    op_flt_carr As String
    op_flt_nbr As Integer
End Type

'Coupon numbers
Public Type cpnNo
    cpn_nbr() As CpnData
End Type
```

```
Public Function FetchCpnData(ByRef tkt As cpnNo) As Variant

    'Declare varbs
    Dim wsCpn As Worksheet
    Dim cpnCnt As Integer
    Dim cnt As Integer
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim lRow As Integer
    
    'Assign varbs
    Set wsCpn = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("tCpn")
    cnt = 1
    With wsCpn
         cpnCnt = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(.Range(Range("tCpn_Fc_Ind").Value2), "Y")
         lRow = .Range("F1") + 2
    End With
    ReDim tkt.cpn_nbr(cpnCnt)
    
    With wsCpn
        For i = 3 To lRow
            If .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Fc_Ind").Column).Value2 = "Y" Then
                'coupon infot
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).cpn_no_prime = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Nbr_Prime").Column).Value2
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).fc_cpn_nbr = cnt
                'depart info
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).dep_airpt = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Dep_Airpt").Column).Value2
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).dep_date = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Dep_Date").Column).Value2
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).dep_time = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_dep_time").Column).Value2
                'arriv info
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).arr_airpt = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Arr_Airpt").Column).Value2
                'carrier info
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).mkt_flt_carr = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Mkt_Flt_Carr").Column).Value2
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).mkt_flt_nbr = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Mkt_Flt_Nbr").Column).Value2
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).op_flt_carr = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Op_Carr").Column).Value2
                tkt.cpn_nbr(cnt).op_flt_nbr = .Cells(i, Range("tCpn_Op_Flt_Nbr").Column).Value2
                cnt = cnt + 1
            End If
        Next i
    End With
    
End Function
```

I then have 4 other functions entered into cells which use the above function, which access the jagged array by calling the function

For example:

```
Public Function DateRange(geo_cpn As String, geo_str As String, eval_cpn As String, fr_yy As String, fr_mm As String, fr_dd As String, to_yy As String, to_mm As String, to_dd As String, tvl_prt As String) As String

    'Declare variables
    Dim tkt As cpnNo
    
    'Assign variables
    Call FetchCpnData(tkt)
```

Because I am using the array created in the first function across 4 other ones, it seems redundant to call it on 4 separate occassions. Therefore, is it possible to pass it by reference to the worksheet functions? I tried this, however on the worksheet, the input was asking for tkt as an input.

Appreciate any advice or input

Comment: What is `cpnNo`? A class? How your code builds that "jagged array"? The function you show does not return such an array...

Comment: If `cpnNo` is a class, in order to reuse it,  it should be declared on top of a standard module and having some properties loaded, before reusing. Or preliminarily checking this aspect and load it (once), if the case. Can you share the class code, too? Does it have a property/method building the jagged array you are talking about? Do you name the class as jagged array, because you gave it some arrays as properties? A jagged array  is an array of arrays. But **an array**...

Comment: @FaneDuru not a class, public type. Please see the edits above

Comment: OK. So, you have to  not locally declare `Dim tkt As cpnNo`. You should declare it on top of the module as `Public tkt As cpnNo`. Then it can be used by any other function/Sub. Since your function `FetchCpnData` does not return anything, it may/should be a `Sub`.  Since, `ByRef` is default, so you can create it as `Sub placeDataInArray(tkt As cpnNo)`. You can read and modify any `tkt.cpn_nbr()` array type element. If you need to extend it, you have  `ReDim Preserve  tkt.cpn_nbr(Ubound(tkt.cpn_nbr) + 5)` and fill the last 5 added elements. And finally, `tkt.cpn_nbr()` is not a jagged array...:)

Comment: One more (important) issue: If you do not load the array in discussion in a specific succession, meaning to all the time firstly running `DateRange`, when you try using it, you should check if it is loaded (or not). In VBA is not so simple, as it should, I am afraid... So, try using the next function: `Function isArrLoaded(arrT As cpnNo) As Boolean` followed by `If Not Not arrT.cpn_nbr() Then isArrLoaded = True` `End Function`. And call it as: `If isArrLoaded(tkt) Then` 'do whatever you want... `End If`...

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like below by using a public variabe for you data. In each use of the UDF it checks if the data was already loaded, if not it loads it. So the data is only loaded at the first time of the UDF and all the other times it uses the already loaded data of the public variable.

Note that does not take into account changed data. So if you change some of the loaded data it will not use that until you run `LoadDataInArray` again.

The data is only loaded once per Excel session (when you open your file and the sheet is calculated the first time).

```
Option Explicit

' create a public variable
Public myArray() As Variant

' create a sub that loads data into that public array
Public Sub LoadDataInArray()
    myArray = Array("test1", "test2", "test3")
End Sub


' create your udf that you use like a formula in Excel cells
Public Function udf_UseCreatedArray() As String
    
    ' check if th array was initialized (has data already)
    If Not Not myArray Then
        ' do nothing
    Else
        ' if it has no data load data
        LoadDataInArray
    End If
    
    ' use your array data
    udf_UseCreatedArray = Join(myArray)  ' as example just return joined array data in cell
End Function
```